# Limits for html selector

Tags: javascript, browser, css-selectors, jquery-selectors, limits

I have some little questions to Web developers.

Does anyone know these limits:

- HTML selector max length?
- HTML max number of selectors in one rule?
- JS selector max length?

And other question:

- Which solution is better? To make 10.000 requests with 1 selector to DOM or make 1 request with 10.000 selectors?

Comment: 10,000 selectors? I can't imagine a page with 10,000 elements!!!

Comment: You can replace this number by "infinity" or just "many".